# tensorflow_hub throwing this error: 'SentencepieceOp' when loading the link

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, tensorflow-hub

The following line of code I am trying to run in PyCharm and I have tensorflow_hub installed and imported.

```
use = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3")
```

Any suggestions for the below error? As I need this for my project.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3820, in _get_op_def
    return self._op_def_cache[type]
KeyError: 'SentencepieceOp'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jon10/OneDrive/Documents/Computer Science/Dissertation/PythonPractice/TFTest/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    use = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3")
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module_v2.py", line 102, in load
    obj = tf_v1.saved_model.load_v2(module_path, tags=tags)
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\load.py", line 517, in load
    return load_internal(export_dir, tags)
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\load.py", line 541, in load_internal
    export_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\load.py", line 114, in __init__
    meta_graph.graph_def.library))
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\function_deserialization.py", line 312, in load_function_def_library
    copy, copy_functions=False)
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\function_def_to_graph.py", line 61, in function_def_to_graph
    fdef, input_shapes, copy_functions)
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\function_def_to_graph.py", line 214, in function_def_to_graph_def
    op_def = ops.get_default_graph()._get_op_def(node_def.op)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Jon10\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3824, in _get_op_def
    c_api.TF_GraphGetOpDef(self._c_graph, compat.as_bytes(type), buf)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'SentencepieceOp' in binary running on DESKTOP-..... Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to install tensorflow_text, and import it before using hub.load

Comment: tensorflow_text can't be used on windows.

Comment: Yes, Tensorflow_Text for Windows is not implemented yet. There is an Open Issue in Github, https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/44, regarding the same. You can use Google Colab or may have to switch to other OS (if possible).

Comment: @jonnb104 indeed, didn't notice you were on windows

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue on Kubuntu (Linux).

Then I have installed `tensorflow-text`.

```
pip3 install tensorflow-text
```

And I imported it like this before call to `hub.load`:

```
import tensorflow_text as text
```

And it worked.